# Shipping Based on Geo Location(Country)

Tags: magento

I'm a beginner in magento and I want the shipping method to be chosen according to the geo location(country), i want it to be automatically chosen if the customer chooses the country.
Anybody has any idea how to do that..

Comment: you need to write your own code in checkout/shipping_method/available.phtml

Answer (score 1):

You should try using an extension like [Owebia 2](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/owebia-shipping-2.html) (you can find [documentation here](http://www.owebia.com/contributions/magento/owebia-shipping/en/))

This'll allow you to set up shipping rates and delivery methods depending on the country of the customer.

Edit: 
You can use this for virtually any shipping like UPS or Fedex (I used it for UPS on the last website I worked on).

Here's some config example

```
# UPS  National (France, Monaco, Andorre)
{
    code: "expressupsnational",
    label: "Service STANDARD France : Livraison 24/48h",
    destination: "FR,MC,AD",
    fees: "{table {cart.weight} in 2:8.5, 12:14.5}",
    tracking_url: "http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track",
}
```

This was for france and set so that fees are related to cart weight (8.5 gold if cart is under 2kg, 14.5 gold if less than 12kg). Note that the label part is the name of the method displayed in frontend, and destination is the list of ISO codes of destination countries.
Next part is for customers coming from Germany, Belgium...

```
# UPS  Zone 5 (DE,BE,LU,AT)
{
    code: "expressupseurope5",
    label: "Service STANDARD Europe: Livraison 48/72h",
    destination: "DE,BE,LU,AT",
    fees: "{table {cart.weight} in 2:12.0, 12:24.0}",
    tracking_url: "http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track",
}
```

If you refer to the doc you'll see that you can add many conditions like attribute set, tax rates, number of products in cart etc... It's way more flexible than original Magento shipping methods.

Comment: your answer is some what correct but i want to use other shipping methods like fedex, ups etc for that i need to give some condition, i need to know how to select shipping based on that condition...